# $\beta$-function in non-Abelian scalar QCD

Tags: quantum-field-theory, lagrangian-formalism, resource-recommendations, gauge-theory, renormalization

I study non-Abelian scalar QCD in $d = 4 - \epsilon$ dimensions (using dimensional reduction). That is, I consider complex scalars, $\Phi^i$ with $i \in \{1, ..., N\}$, that satisfies $U(N)$-symmetry, and which is coupled to non-Abelian guage fields, $A_\mu^a$ with $a \in\{1, ..., \text{dim } G\}$ where $G$ is the non-Abelian gauge group. The Lagrangian for the theory is given by
\begin{equation}
\mathcal{L} = - \frac{(F_{\mu\nu}^a)^2}{4} - \frac{|D_\mu\Phi^i|^2}{2} + \frac{\lambda}{4!}|\Phi^i|^4 \ ,
\end{equation}
where $D_\mu$ is the covariant derivative
\begin{equation}
D_\mu = \partial_\mu + i e A_\mu \ , \quad A_\mu = T^aA_\mu^a \ ,
\end{equation}
and $F_{\mu\nu}^a$ is the field strength
\begin{equation}
F_{\mu\nu}^a = \partial_\mu A_\nu^a - \partial_\nu A_\mu^a + e f^{abc}A^b_\mu A^c_\nu \ .
\end{equation}
Here $f^{abc}$ is the structure constant of $G$, and $T^a$ is its generator.

In particular, I wish to find the $\beta$-functions for the couplings $\lambda$ and $e$ upto one-loop. I'm mostly wondering whether this has been studied before, and if so, is there a good reference which I can use to double check my result?

Comment: For the gauge coupling, see https://arxiv.org/abs/1312.2684 equation (3.1.1).

Comment: Thanks! I appreciate it!